# Updating mysql (json) with several quotes (don't want escape characters in database)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a Json datatype inside a database (row format = longtext).

Le'ts say this is the data I want to copy and put into another field via PHP (using PDO):

{"migration1": "something something",
"migration2": "something something something",
"migration69": "["something1", "something2", "something3"]"}

My Problem lays with the data in migration69.

Here is the SQL satement:

UPDATE `mytable` SET `myfield`=(SELECT JSON_SET(`myfield`,
'$.migration1', :mig1,
'$.migration2', :mig2,
'$.migration69', :mig69
)
FROM `mytable` WHERE `id`=1234)
WHERE `id`=1234

When I execute the statement in PHP it does puts excape characters into my database before every quotation mark exept for the first and last one (it does not show them here...):

"migration69": "["something1", "something2", "something3"]"

But i do need it EXACTLY like this but without the escape characters.

I sure have tried around a bit but maybe there is an easy solution?

Cheers for some help - i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't build your JSON by hand, use json_encode. And don't build your SQL queries with concatenation, use parameters and prepared statements. In other words, follow established best practices and features that people have provided to do these tasks correctly, instead of making your own. That should take care of your escaping issues.

Comment: Hi! I did use a prepared statement and also tried the json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE. Still - when it updates it in the database there are escape characters in front of each quote inside the string. :-(

Comment: You'll need to show us precisely what code and data you used, and precisely what result you got. We can't fix it just from a vague description.